# Defining a modified get interface in a cache

Tags: java, caching

Good Morning,

Our service uses a cache that synchronizes with the current state of the db every once in a while in a periodic fashion. However, there is an issue that if the service were to re-start
for some reason, then some of the less frequently updated caches haven't received their copy of data yet { because the periodic task hasn't been scheduled yet }, so there is more downtime. I'm thinking of adding a modified getter interface passing in a functor that would get the value from the database if it were not found in the cache. The problem is coming from a c++ background I need some feedback on the correct java way of doing this.

I was thinking on adding an interface like this.

```
V getOrGenerateForKey(final Key k, final Function<Key, V> foo)
```

Is there any other java classes that capture the idea better or provide cleaner solutions?

Thanks, Subramanian

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) in Guava. It's [CacheLoader](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) is the 'generate' and 'update' part of your interface and the Cache built by the `CacheBuilder` is the 'get'.